# Draw line from tabular cell within a node

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a line from a tabular cell within a node.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newcommand{\mk}[2]{\tikz \node (#1) {#2};}%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \node (N1) [shape=rectangle] {
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{title} \\ \hline
        \mk{A}{11} & 12 & 13 \\ \hline
        21 & 22 & 23 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    };  
    \node[right=1cm of N1,draw] (N2) {X};
    \draw[<->,red] (A) -- ([yshift=1cm]A) -| (N2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

But:

1. the cell marked with tikz command shift a little bit.
2. output not from the cell.
   [image]

Comment: This nests `tikzpicture`s, which is not supported, and leads to random results. Would using a matrix to generate the tabular be an option? If not, perhaps using a `\subnode` that ships with `tikzmark`?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I prefer tabular since matrix need too many tweaks as a table. how \subnode work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach nests `tikzpicture`s, which is not supported. There are two obvious options I can see:

1. Use `tikzmark`s `\subnode`.
2. Use a `matrix`.

Here they are

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,remember picture]
    \node (N1) [shape=rectangle] {
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|}
        \multicolumn{3}{c}{title} \\ \hline
        \subnode{A}{11} & 12 & 13 \\ \hline
        21 & 22 & 23 \\ \hline
        \end{tabular}
    };  
    \node[right=1cm of N1,draw] (N2) {X};
    \draw[<->,red] (A.north) -- ++(0,0.5) -| (N2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    \path node[matrix,matrix of nodes,label=above:title,
        cells={nodes={draw}},
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2]
    (N)
    {    11 & 12 & 13 \\ 
        21 & 22 & 23 \\ 
    };  
    \node[right=1cm of N-2-3,draw] (N2) {X};
    \draw[<->,red] (N-1-1)  -| (N2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, for solution 1, if change A to A.center in the draw command, then everything works fine. not sure why!

Comment: @lucky1928 I changed it to something that looks IMO fine. (Anyway, this is sort of off-topic.)